# Longest subarray with sum greater than K

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I was trying to understand the code at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-subarray-having-sum-greater-than-k/amp/

However, I am not following it.

Specifically, I did not understand the following:

1. what does minInd array hold?
2. What is the use of minInd in keeping track of largest subarray?
3. What does find method return?

Illustration with an example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial approach is to do it in O(N^2) time. However you can do it O(N log N) time on expense of space. This solution doesn't follow geeksforgeeks precisely but  will give you O(N Log N) solution. I have attached image for better understanding.

Lets take an input array (-2, 3,1,-2,1,1) and create prefix sum array.

A **prefix sum array** is sum of all elements up to current element: [-2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
e.g: at index 2 in input array sum of all the elements before and including it : -2+3+1=2

Please note that :In below approach Prefix sub array  and array implies the same thing. For original input array I will call it original array.

1. you create a prefix sum array and store the index use to create this prefix sum array (0-5) and put it into a queue.
2. Take the first content ( prefix sum array) out of the queue. Now if your last value in the prefix sum array is greater than or equal to K then the index you used to create this array is the answer.
3. If not then lets break this prefix array in two sub prefix sum array and add both of them in the queue. Store their index too.

- One  consisting of sub prefix array from prefix sum array's start to its end -1.  - Second part ( slight change) consisting of prefix sum array from start+1 to end. In the second part you have to subtract the first element from each element present in the sub array (if you check the attached image it will become quite apparent).

Go back to step 2 and repeat until either Queue is empty or you find solution.

Further optimization : you can use memoization to reduce branching . if you have already processed a prefix sub array sum then no need to re-evaluate it again.

Below is the diagram where input is transformed into Prefix array sum and broken down repeatedly into prefix sub array sum until last element of our prefix sub array sum >=k

[image: diagram]

Note: each node consist of key : the index we are considering for prefix sub array. Value = the actual prefix array sum

Hopefully it will be clearer from the diagram.

1. Lets say your k=3 and input array =(-2, 3,1,-2,1,1)
2. you create prefix sum array =[{0-5=[-2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]}]
3. since the last element in the prefix sum array <k you split into two parts

- sub array from 0-4=> [-2, 1, 2, 0, 1]
- sub array from 1-5=> [1, 2, 0, 1, 2] ( and subtract -2 from each element ) to get [3, 4, 2, 3, 4]  a proper prefix sub array
- Now your last element in the prefix sub array sum is 4 ( greater than K ) your answer giving you the index of such sub array is 1-5